# How can i get Array values to separate php variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to retrieve records in MySQL DB.I want to retrieve all the records belong to the img_path column.from the following code I am getting results as an array.but iw ant them as separate variables.

My code

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result_list[] = $row;
}
foreach($result_list as $row) {

    $productitems[] = array(
        'img_path' => $row['img_path'],
    );

}

print_r($productitems);
```

Current Output

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [img_path] => img/8041171eda3a8fddf508bfd0d9a0866e1472441466.png ) 
[1] => Array ( [img_path] => img/91882b5f9ffa624a9dc81dfa0ec980861472441077.jpg ) 
[2] => Array ( [img_path] => img ) )
```

expected output

```
$variable1 = img/8041171eda3a8fddf508bfd0d9a0866e1472441466.png;
$variable2 = img/91882b5f9ffa624a9dc81dfa0ec980861472441077.jpg;
```

Comment: Try following `$productitems = array(); // Initialize outside for loop` `$productitems[] = $row['img_path'];`

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam That just creates another array, which is rather counter-productive when OP asked to get the values in separate variables.

Comment: Why do you want ever output in a separate variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract` function like this:

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result_list[] = $row;
}
foreach($result_list as $row) {
    $productitems[] = $row['img_path'];
}
extract($productitems, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "variable");
echo $variable_0;
echo $variable_1;
echo $variable_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result_list[] = $row;
}

foreach($result_list as $k => $row) {
    $varName = 'var' . $k;

    $$varName = array(
        'img_path' => $row['img_path'],
    );

}
```

And you will have access to $var0, $var1, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You might use, `extract()` function. Docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

> The extract() function imports variables into the local symbol table
>   from an array.
>
> This function uses array keys as variable names and values as variable
>   values. For each element it will create a variable in the current
>   symbol table.
>
> This function returns the number of variables extracted on success.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list()`.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
```

From the manual:

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";
```

Comment: But you have to consider: `list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0`

Comment: Thanks @PhilippPalmtag. I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code, where you do not need to use an additional function like `list()` or `extract()`. It is also a very minimalistic approach.

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result_list[] = $row;
}

foreach($result_list as $key => $row) {
    ${'img_path_'.$key} = $row['img_path'];
}

/*
Output:
["img_path_0"]=>
  string(50) "img/8041171eda3a8fddf508bfd0d9a0866e1472441466.png"
["img_path_1"]=>
  string(50) "img/91882b5f9ffa624a9dc81dfa0ec980861472441077.jpg"
["img_path_2"]=>
  string(3) "img"
*/
```